# jquery append with dynamic divs from php loop

Tags: php, jquery, html, position, append

Here is a sample fiddle that I have working - http://jsfiddle.net/cuvsc/1/

It does what it's supposed to.  It  appends child divs  to a parent div and sets the offset of child  to be relative to the parent div(not body).
So when I add br or p tags above the parent div it doesn't affect the childs position within the parent.

The problem now is that when I generate that jQuery code from a php database call,the position of the child divs no longer stay relative to the parent.

Could this be from a client side server side issue and what executes first?  The code in the fiddle is the code that would come out of the database.

Maybe my selector is wrong?

Here is the code

```
<?
while ($row = $result->fetch_object())  {
    $dbchildNumber=$row->dbChildNumber;
    $cords=$row->coordTopLeft;
?>
    <div id="child_<?=  $dbchildNumber ?>" class="multidraggable" style="position: absolute;">
    <?=$boothNumber ?>
    </div>
<?php
    $i++;
}
?>
```

the parent div and jquery code for positioning

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
    $arrPos = explode(",", $row->coordTopLeft);
    echo "$('.parent').append($('#child_" . $row->childNumber . "'));\n\n";
    echo "$('#child_" . $row->childNumber . "').offset({left:" . $arrPos[0] . ",top:" . $arrPos[1] . "});\n\n";

    $i++;
}
```

that was Cut and pasted from php page.

I can't figure out what I am missing.  Any ideas?   Maybe it would also help others with positioning too or php used with jQuery?

Comment: Can you provide the rendered html from the browser rather than the php?

Comment: the html for those elements being generated are in the jfiddle. the two child divs that are the result of the php are  <div id="child_123" class="multidraggable" style="position: absolute;background: #ddff33;">
123</div><br>
<div id="child_303" class="multidraggable" style="position: absolute;background: #cc9999;">
303
</div>

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the fiddle and the html that would be generated by the php code is that the fiddle has the child elements with `position: absolute` but the html generated by php is set to `postion: relative`.

Comment: Sorry, bad copy paste as I was trying different things.  I updated the code above to be position: absolute as it is in my local code.  It doesn't work that way either though.  I am scrutinizing the code agin now with firebug and will post if anything comes to light.